# Extraction of whois data for country level domains( .us/.uk etc)

Tags: domains, whois

I'm using Domaintools.com whois api to get the whois info about domains. But they don't have data for country level domains like .us/.au etc.

Is there any place I get the whois info using some api for many country level domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look [RoboWhois](http://www.robowhois.com/). We support [all TLDs](http://docs.robowhois.com/api/supported-tlds/) with a public WHOIS service, including .US, .AU, and .UK.

*Disclaimer:* I'm the author of the service.

Comment: Simone thanks for this but curious why DomainTools could not provide whois for such domains while you are able to.

Comment: In order to provide whois details for a WHOIS server you need to create a specific WHOIS parser. Each server, in fact, returns a different response string. In the last 3 years I created more than 260 different parsers. As you probably imagine, it's a lot of work! ;) Chances are DomainTools has no parser for such TLDs.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ionfish.org/whois/ (An example tool) uses the following method: http://fixee.org/paste/0rj1oj0/

The script comes from here: http://www.phpwhois.org